# Cant define TypeScript dictionary

Tags: dictionary, typescript

I was trying to define a dictionary that maps keys to numbers.
I found this **{[key: string]: number}**.

```
var x: {[key: string]: number} = {
    a: 33,
    b: 25
}

x.a = 32; // Property 'a' does not exist on type: {[key: string]: number;}

x['a'] = 32; // works as expected
x['b'] = '22';  // Type 'string' is no assignable to type 'number'
```

[Link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20x%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%2033%2C%0D%0A%09b%3A%2025%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ax.a%20%3D%2032%3B%20%2F%2F%20Property%20'a'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%3B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ax%5B'a'%5D%20%3D%2032%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%20as%20expected%0D%0Ax%5B'b'%5D%20%3D%20'22'%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Type%20'string'%20is%20no%20assignable%20to%20type%20'number'%0D%0A)

But, This solution is not complete. It works when I am trying to access properties with [] bracelets. But not as an object properties.
Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible. The whole purpose of the type system is to allow you to define known structure of the objects you describe. Otherwise you can just go with `any` as a type.

But you can use object literals like in the sample below, that will allow you to explicitly specify some of the known properties if your dictionary:

```
let x: { PropA: number, [x: string]: number };
x = { PropA: 1, PropX: 2, PropY: 3, PropZ: 4 };
console.log(x.PropA);
console.log(x["PropX"]);
```

Comment: But, I won't be able to do: console.log(x.PropB) only console.log(x['propB']). This does not what I want to do..